# Master Theorem when B is a fraction.

Tags: asymptotics

So I'm working through my homework, and applying the Master Theorem pretty easily, then my prof throws me a curve ball

> $T(n) = 4T(3n/4) + n^4$

Now I used my usual steps of listing out what A, B, and f(n) is:

a = 4
b = 3/4
$f(n) = n^4$

but $\log_{3/4} 4$ does not work out to be a nice a number to fiddle around with in the masters theorem. So is this the right path? Or is there some special rule that applies when b = 3/4?

Comment: I thought the question was more interesting with *faction* than with *fraction*...

Comment: @GEdgar, you're right, but I changed it anyway.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with fractions, just be brave.

Comment: So i should just go ahead with using 3/4 as my b?

Answer (score 2):

When using the *Master Theorem* $b$ symbols the number the $n$ that n is **divided** by ($\frac{n}{b}$),
Thus, your $b$ should be $\frac{4}{3}$ since $\frac{n}{\frac{4}{3}} = \frac{3n}{4}$.

The $b$ you chose symbols the number that $n$ is **multiplied** by, and we are not interested in this number at all.